# Safari won't fallback an AVIF picture

Tags: javascript, html, image, browser, safari

I'm trying to render an image with the below code:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://75tm.gr/GFXS1205/2048/GFXS1205.avif">
  <source srcset="https://75tm.gr/GFXS1205/2048/GFXS1205.webp">
  <img src="https://75tm.gr/GFXS1205/2048/GFXS1205.jpg">
</picture>
```

On Safari browsers, the image is not getting rendered at all. If I delete the first `source` though that has the `.avif` format, then Safari displays correctly the fallback `.jpg` image.

[View on JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cu6rs3yf/1/)

Is this a Safari bug? If so, this really prevents the usage of the `.avif` format. Does anyone know of a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Safari can't fallback if you don't provide `type` attribute. So you need something like this (tested on Safari, works fine for me):

```html
<picture>
  <source srcset="https://75tm.gr/GFXS1205/2048/GFXS1205.avif" type="image/avif">
  <source srcset="https://75tm.gr/GFXS1205/2048/GFXS1205.webp" type="image/webp">
  <img src="https://75tm.gr/GFXS1205/2048/GFXS1205.jpg">
</picture>
```

Comment: Nice! I didn't know Safari is that picky... :P

Comment: not working on some versions i tried iphone 14 safari v16

Answer (score 2):

Still not working on safari v18. It looks like this version now supports avif format. It tries to load avif image what obviously fails without any fallback to jpg (because it assumes it can load avifs). Ill just use jpegs only untill this will be fixed.

Comment: Anything known yet? This is a big issue for developers.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem.

My code is the following.

```
<picture>
  <source type="image/avif" srcset="/img/F11nV5J3VH-600.avif 600w, /img/F11nV5J3VH-1200.avif 1200w" sizes="600px">
  <source type="image/webp" srcset="/img/F11nV5J3VH-600.webp 600w, /img/F11nV5J3VH-1200.webp 1200w" sizes="600px">
  <source type="image/png" srcset="/img/F11nV5J3VH-600.png 600w, /img/F11nV5J3VH-1200.png 1200w" sizes="600px">
  <img alt="Andrea Verlicchi" decoding="async" src="/img/F11nV5J3VH-600.png" width="1200" height="1200">
</picture>
```

I'm quite expert with images and the HTML code looks correct to me. It's generated by Eleventy.

I can't understand why Safari 16.5.1 can't render the AVIF image.

Same, if I delete the source with `type/avif`, it renders the WebP image.

I think it's a Safari bug.